# Write date/time in a AWS Lambda script which triggers SNS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

First time on here
I've just got an Amazon IOT Button and so far i'm 90% of the way to acheiving what I need with it which is to:
Send an SMS to a group of people on button push.

So I've made an SNS Topic with a few SMS subscribers and its working fine with a lambda script which sends a pre-defined message to the topic. 
However I want to be able to put the current date & time in the SMS that goes out.

Current lamba script:
    sns.publish({
    Message: 'Todays FMB for Wigston has been delivered to the collection 
    point',
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx1683:WigstonFMB'

I want the message to say Todays (date) FMB for Wigston has been delivered to the collection point at (time)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Javascript - Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
Alternative: [moment.js](https://github.com/moment/moment)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: this is the full code without a few opening lines ` console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n"); var sns = new AWS.SNS(); sns.publish({ Message: 'Todays FMB for Wigston has been delivered to the collection point', Subject: 'FMB Delivery Notification', TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:153287411xxx:WigstonFMB' }, function(err, data) { if (err) { console.log(err.stack); return; } }); };` –

Comment: ive tried various date tags in the message field but it just prints the tag reference rather than the date

Answer (score 1):

Just get the todays date and add it to the message parameter, you can do it like this:

```
 const date = new Date(Date.now()).toString();
 const date2 = date.substring(0,16);
 const time = date.substring(16,24);
 const params = {
     TopicArn : 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxx1683:WigstonFMB',
     Message: `Todays ${date2} FMB for Wigston has been delivered to the collection point at ${time}`
  }
 sns.publish(params, (err,data)=>{

 })
```

Comment: Be careful -- Lambda and EC2 run in UTC, so you might have to do a timezone adjustment to have that timestamp appear sensible for users.

Comment: @ozbey Didnt work. this is the full code without a few opening lines `
console.log("\n\nLoading handler\n\n");
    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    sns.publish({
        Message: 'Todays FMB for Wigston has been delivered to the collection point',
        Subject: 'FMB Delivery Notification',
        TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:153287411xxx:WigstonFMB'
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            return;
        }
    });
};`